# Bazel build file load multiple dependencies

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-python

I have a Python repo that contains two requirement files. In my `WORKSPACE` file, I imported both the dependencies.

*requirements-1.txt*:

```
numpy
```

*requirements-2.txt*:

```
scipy
```

*WORKSPACE*:

```
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_install")

pip_install(
    name = "deps_1",
    requirements = "//:requirements-1.txt",
)

pip_install(
    name = "deps_2",
    requirements = "//folder2:requirements-2.txt",
)
```

I have a BUILD file like this:

```
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_library")
load("@deps_1//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
load("@deps_2//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")


py_library(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test.py"],
    deps = [
        requirement("numpy"),
        requirement("scipy"),
    ],
)
```

The build can't import numpy

```
no such package '@deps//pypi__numpy': BUILD file not found in directory 'pypi__numpy' of external repository @deps2. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
```

How do I load two dependencies in the same BUILD file?

Comment: Please add the Bazel command you used to build or run your project. Which Bazel version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can do this by loading the two `requirement`s with different names. Like this:

```py
load("@deps_1//:requirements.bzl", deps_1_requirement = "requirement")
load("@deps_2//:requirements.bzl", deps_2_requirement = "requirement")
```

Then you can use `deps_1_requirement("numpy")` and `deps_2_requirement("scipy")`.

However, with those two particular libraries, scipy depends on numpy. If you load both of them, you'll end up with two different numpy copies. If they're both the same version, it'll probably work. If they're different versions, you might run into weird issues. I think you can just drop numpy from the list and your code should be able to import the single version that pip/rules_python bring in because it's a dependency of scipy.